# break a text file into parts/lines and place the parts into text boxes

Tags: c#

Right now my code takes the entire text file and just places it all into one text box.  What I am trying to figure out how to do is have it place each line of the file into each separate text box.

```
namespace HomeInventory2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1(string prepopulated)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBoxAmount.Text = prepopulated;
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateInventory create = new CreateInventory();
            create.ItemAmount = textBoxAmount.Text;
            create.ItemCategory = textBoxCategories.Text;
            create.ItemProperties = textBoxValue.Text;
            create.ItemValue = textBoxValue.Text;

            InventoryMngr invtryMngr = new InventoryMngr();
            invtryMngr.Create(create);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the order of the lines is always the same and that each `TextBox` belongs to a line:

```
IEnumerable<String> lines = File.ReadLines(path);
textBoxAmount.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
textBoxCategories.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(1);
textBoxValue.Text = lines.ElementAtOrDefault(2);
...
```

[`Enumerable.ElementAtOrDefault<TSource>` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx)

> Returns the element at a specified index in a sequence or a default
>   value if the index is out of range (null in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You could use System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(string filename).
What this does is reads each line of the file into a String array. 
You could then do something like:

```
using System.IO;


//Namespace, Class Blah Blah BLah


String[] FileLines = File.ReadAllLines("Kablooey");


textBox1.Text = FileLines[0];

textbox2.Text = FileLines[1];
```

And so on. I hope this helps :)